# reflection plane 3d

Tags: camera, matrix, reflection-rendering

Hey there I'm trying to create a plane that can have a texture on it and reflect the 3d elements around it. for example a plane with a laminate floor texture and above it a cube rotating. I want the plane to retain the floor texture but have a reflection of the cube.

I've been trying to figure out how to go about doing this. I'm using flash stage3d capabilities and a 3d engine but i'm sure the same principles will apply from other engines and languages.

From what I can tell I create some kind of reflection matrix from the plane? and then use that somehow with the camera position?

Any further info/drawings/guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

1)Create a plane that usually contain a point and a normal that represents the floor.

2)Reflect your camera position and rotation from this plane.

3)Create a view matrix from these point and rotation.

4)Render scene from this matrix into a texture.

5)Transmiss those texture and matrix into a shader.

6)Project texture onto a surface of floor using transmissed matrix.

7)???

8)PROFIT!